# Reflection of a line on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the reflection of $z$ on the line $ax+by=c$, where $a,b,c \in
>  \mathbb{R}$ is given by the following: $$\frac{2ic+(b-ai)\bar z}{b+ai}$$

I know that the conjugate of $z$, which is $\bar z$, will be the reflection of the point $z$ in the real axis, but I don't know how to proceed further in proving this.

Comment: Was a definition of reflection given to you?

Comment: Is there maybe an $a$ missing with $2ic$?

Comment: Probably not, if you reflect $z = 0$ at the vertical line $2·x + 0·y = 2$, this formula yields $\tfrac{4·i}{2·i} = 2$, the correct result, the formula of my calculations give you $4$, which is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solutions depends on whether $a ≠ 0$ or $b ≠ 0$.

Translate the problem to the origin. $z ↦ z-\tfrac{c}{a}$ or $z ↦ z - i\tfrac{c}{b}$

Spin the line onto the real line. $z ↦ \tfrac{z}{b-ai}$

Reflect the plane at the real line. $z ↦ \overline z$

Spin back to the former line . $z ↦ (b-ai) z$

Translate to your former point. $z ↦ z + \tfrac{c}{a}$ or $z ↦ z + i\tfrac{c}{b}$

All in all I get: $(b-ai)\overline{\left(\tfrac{z-\tfrac{c}{a}}{b-ai}\right)} + \tfrac{c}{a} = \tfrac{2ic + (b-ai)\overline z}{b+ai}$ (And the same with the other variant.)

**Note**: I think something's wrong with this as it should be $2ic$ instead of $2iac$. I can't figure it out, but I really want to know what my error is.

*This is now corrected.*

Comment: There must be something wrong with this, but I don't know what it is. If I don't findit , I'll delete this post. Or maybe I won't, so someone else can find it. I'm really interested.

Comment: Keep it please, hopefully someone can go over it. THanks a lot!

Comment: @K.Stm The problem is in both translations. First subtract $\frac{c}{a}$ and at last add $\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: @RicardoCruz Thanks, I see my mistake now. I updated the answer.