# "Reflection of a line on complex plane"; why is $b-ai$ that which rotates the line?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm sorry to make a new question about this, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I'm trying to do the exact same problem as has already been answered; "[Reflection of a line on complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287567/reflection-of-a-line-on-complex-plane)". This is exercise 1.2.19 (page 13) from the third edition of "Fundamentals of Complex Analysis", E.B. Saff, A.D. Snider.

What I don't understand is rotation using $z\mapsto \frac{z}{b-ai} $. We have $a$ and $b$ which is in $ax+by=c$ and $b-ai$. I understand that dividing by a complex number rotates $z$, but I don't understand why $b-ai$ is the correct vector to do this.

Should not this vector also be normalized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why that rotation does what it does

It's really probably better to think of *multiplication* as making rotations, although of course division and multiplication are really the same. In that spirit, look at this:

$$
\frac{z}{b-ai}=z(\frac{b+ai}{a^2+b^2})
$$

Here we can see that $z$ is being multiplied by a complex number of unit length (here you can see it's already normalized) on the right hand side, which we know effects a rotation on the complex plane. It isn't normalized , so it will contribute dilation, but that's OK: two steps later the inverse transformation contributes a dilation factor that cancels this one's dilation out. All that matters is that this transformation carries our line onto the $x$-axis.

So on the step you're at, the line has been translated so that it goes through the origin, so its points all fall on $ax+by=0$.

Let $(x',y')$ be on $ax+by=0$. After rotation by the above mapping, $(x',y')\mapsto (bx'-ay',ax'+by')/(a^2+b^2)$. But since $ax'+by'=0$, this is just $((bx'-ay')/(a^2+b^2),0)$, so the line has been laid on the $x$-axis, as advertised.

From the last paragraph you can see how this can be reverse engineered. If one had applied an arbitrary rotation $(x,y)\mapsto((cx-dy)/(c^2+d^2),cx+dy)$, and they were armed with the equation $ax+by=0$, and you asked them "What choice of $c$ and $d$ makes this rotation put $x,y$ on the $x$ axis? They might say "how about $c=a$ and $d=b$?"

---

*Moved this here since it turned out to be a digression.*

<s>Looking at the map as an $\Bbb R$ linear transformation on $\Bbb C$, and viewing the inputs as column vectors $[x,y]^\top$ that correspond to $x+yi$, you can confirm that this matrix accomplishes the transformation by multiplication on the left of the column vectors:</s>

$$
\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{bmatrix}b&-a\\a&b\end{bmatrix}
$$

It's a matrix with determinant $1$ (of course it should be, since it represents a complex number of unit modulus) and so it's a rotation of $\Bbb R^2$ (which is being identified with $\Bbb C$.)

Comment: Isn't $\frac{b+ai}{a^2+b^2}$ a complex number?

Comment: @john.abraham Yes? So is $\frac{1}{b-ai}$, which it is equal to.

Comment: It's just that you write that $z$ is being multiplied by a real number of unit length; is it supposed to be " a complex number of unit length"?

Comment: I tried using the mapping you described with $4x-2y=0$ and the point $(x',y')=(1,2)$, but that maps $(1,2)$ to the point $(-0.5,0)$, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @john.abraham Aha, you're right: I misdiagnosed $\frac{b+ai}{a^2+b^2}$ as being normalized, but $\frac{b+ai}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ is the right normalization. You were observing that a length $\sqrt{5}$ thing was being rotated to a length $0.5$ thing, and that's because the thing we are multiplying with dialates and rotates. Fortunately the later inverse rotation cancels out this dilation. I'll revise my answer to incorporate this. Good work on finding this!

Comment: I still can't make this work: If you take the line $4x-2y=0$ ($y=2x$) you have $(a,b)=(4,-2)$. A complex number on the line could be $z=2+4i$. The fraction $\frac{z}{b-ai}$ yields $\frac{2+4i}{-2-4i}$ which doesn't rotate $z$ to the real line. What am I missing here?

Comment: @john.abraham $\frac{2+4i}{-2-4i}=-1$, which is on the real axis... what did you get instead? $3+6i$ is also on that line, and $\frac{3+6i}{-2-4i}=\frac{3(1+2i)}{-2(1+2i)}=\frac{3}{-2}$ again is on the real axis. In general for any complex number on the line, the number is a scalar multiple of $1+2i$, so it will always cancel and leave a real number.

Comment: So I could divide by $1-\frac{a}{b}i$ as well as $b-ai$?

Comment: Well I tried using $1-\frac{a}{b}$ and I got the right answer. I guess what I don't understand is why $b-ai$ has the same angle as the line $ax+by=0$. This might be a middle school level hole in my knowledge, I would be super grateful if someone explained this to me or gave me an appropriate link.

Comment: @john.abraham $1-\frac{ai}{b}$ is just $b-ai$ divided by a real number, so the only difference between the two is scaling. So yes, it will also rotate the line to the horizontal (as $b-ai$ does). I don't know what you mean by a complex number having an angle. All I know is that complex multiplication effects rotations and dilations upon the complex plane. The analytic justification in the solution (using coordinates) is the simplest way to see this, for me. I think it's above middle school level :) Regards.

Comment: @john.abraham Ah, I guess you mean that $b-ai$ has the right Arg to rotate the line to the horizontal. I'll try to think of another explanation.

Comment: I'm just going to post this last comment before accepting the answer. Take the line $ax+by=0$ and solve it for $y$, then we get $y=-\frac{a}{b}x$. To get a point on the line we can chose $x=1$ and we get $(1,-\frac{a}{b})$, so we know $1-\frac{a}{b}i$ is on the line. We can scale it how we want, so why not $b(1-\frac{a}{b})=b-ai$. So $b-ai$ is also on the line, so $\frac{z}{b-ai}$ is what we want. What I didn't understand was that $b-ai$ is a on the line $ax+by=0$. Thank you.